# Lost document sojourno? help

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lost-documents

My Parents have id documents sourjourno stay for Italy. They went to India and lost their documents  - it was apparently reported. As they cannot look after themselves i have booked them to come back. They have been in India for 2 years. WIll they be refused entry into Italy. WIll Delhi immigration let them board. Is there a restriction on how long they can leave Italy for? What will happen if we show them the document. WIll they be rejected? please help?

Comment: Did they replace their lost documents? They should have contacted an Italian consulate immediately upon discovering the loss.

Comment: Also, what nationality are they?

Comment: If your parents had a Carta Di Soggiorno then their right to live in Italy lapsed once they were outside Italy for more than 12 months. If this is the case they'll need to re-apply. At the very least they'll need a Schengen visa to enter Italy. The situation is better if they had an EU long-term residence permit, but they'll need to replace it before they travel. It's unlikely they'll be allowed to board without either a visa or a permit. However, questions about long term residence belong on [expatriates.se]. You should ask there.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.